# Html page doesn't print German correctly in utf-8

Tags: python, html, django, utf-8, multilingual

I have a python-django project that saves German and italian. The only way I don't have a problem with encoding is by adding in my Html form that post information to be saved in the database is this:

```
 <form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="" accept-charset="ISO-8859-7">
```

If I want to print the list of saved information with

```
content = content.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
return HttpResponse(content)
```

it returns in the browser umlaut(blätterte ab) and everything correct.

If I try to return it to an Html page and print it with django in a table I get text like this: es bl&#228;tterte ab

I added in response that redirects to the html page this (where new_vars is the list o json objects etc):

```
MIME_TYPES = {'html': 'text/html',
          'xml': 'application/xml'}
content = render_raw(template_name, new_vars, type="html")
mimetype = MIME_TYPES[type]
return HttpResponse(content, mimetype=mimetype,content_type="text/html; charset=utf-8")
```

I also added in HTML page this:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but still the same problem. I am using python 2.7.2+ and I cannot upgrade it.

Comment: Isn't German and Italian covered by `ISO-8859-1` (the `accept-charset=` in your form is set to `ISO-8859-7`)?  Anyway, if your page has the `meta` tag with `charset=utf-8` the browser shall use UTF-8 when sending the `form`, i'd try removing the `accept-charset=`.  Then, in Django, i'd remove the `convert` calls.  If that is not sufficient i'd add `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.  I assume you're not involving a database for the current processing (table columns might be non-UTF-8 if Django is not the one creating them).

Comment: I had a problem with saving them in database with ISO-8869-1. I tried many solutions I found but nothing worked (decode, encode to utf-8 etc). They only answered me that I should update to python 3 which is not possible. There is a database involved that saves it as  bl&\#228;tterte ab . So this is why I use decode.encode to print it correctly. I removed everything you referred still the same.

Comment: Please tell us more about the database you're using.  `VARCHAR`s in different databases might be configured in different ways (with different encodings for a start).  And, even more importantly, tell us whether it is Django that has full control over the database or other applications use this database as well.  For example, `postgres` under Django's control would always set its `VARCHAR`s to UTF-8 encoding, but that is not what you're seeing.

Comment: It is postgres under Django's control. And I saw from the settings that it is default UTF-8. But I don't think the problem is in database. I manage to decode it to UTF-8 and when I use simple return HttpResponse(content) the German language is properly returned. But if I use HttpResponse to return to a certain Html page and print content with django inside an html page is not returned correctly. Why is returned correctly with simple return HttpResponse(content) and not to a template html page.

Comment: Are you sure that when you read "bl&\#228;tterte ab" from the database you are in a UTF-8 environment?  `psql` is UTF-8 aware, and shall not be printing a UTF-8 `VARCHAR` in that form.  I'm asking this because i suspect that what is inserting the data into the table is screwing the encoding.